# Photoshop like canvas image droppable, scalable images position absolute issue while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

there I have a problem with making images drop inside canvas that I made (not canvas tag). I am dropping images into my canvas. I gave it a click and drag option that enables properties window, that can change its CSS. When I scale image with transform scale, images with initial position: absolute property, behave weird while dragging (jquery UI draggable) and changes its location under the mouse, what is looking like the image (if smaller) is under the mouse or over it (if bigger scale). So I removed position absolute. But now when I add images to canvas, one is added under another so if the image is bigger than canvas it's relocated somewhere down below.

```
function newImage(image){
var img = new Image()
img.onload = function (){
    imgWidth[image.id] = img.naturalWidth
    console.log(img.naturalWidth)
    imgHeight[image.id] = img.naturalHeight
    console.log(img.naturalHeight)
}
img.src = image.url
    $('#canvas').append('' +

            '<div id="img-'+image.id+'" class="selectable" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; outline-offset: -2px; position: absolute">' +
                '<img class="realImg" id="realImg-'+image.id+'" src="'+image.url+'" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; mix-blend-mode: unset;">' +// to ma .nameide i .speed
            '</div>'
    )
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#img-'+image.id).css('width', imgWidth[image.id])
        //$('#realImg-'+image.id).css('width', imgWidth[image.id])
        $('#img-'+image.id).css('height', imgHeight[image.id])
        //$('#realImg-'+image.id).css('height', imgHeight[image.id])
    }, 100)
        $('#img-'+image.id).draggable({
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                activeImg = "#img-"+image.id
                activeImgId = image.id
                $('.selectable').removeClass('border-blend')
                console.log('reselect')
                $('#img-'+activeImgId).addClass('border-blend')
                console.log('selected')
                console.log('aktywny '+activeImg)
                $('#formPosX').val(parseInt($(activeImg).css('left')))
                $('#formPosY').val(parseInt($(activeImg).css('top')))
            }
        })
            $('.realImg').each(function (index) {
                $(this).click(function (){
                    if ( $(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging') ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $('.selectable').removeClass('border-blend')
                    activeImgId = $(this).attr('id').split("-")[1]
                    activeImg = '#img-'+activeImgId
                    $(activeImg).addClass('border-blend')
                    console.log('selected')
                    console.log('aktywny '+activeImg)
                    $('#formPosX').val(parseInt($(activeImg).css('left')))
                    $('#formPosY').val(parseInt($(activeImg).css('top')))
                })
            })
}
```

I was thinking about changing the position to `relative` as I think draggable is using, after starting dragging. But first drag click is with this problem of images being relocated and next are not (they are fine). Next thing I was thinking on making relative, when timeout is runoff, images go down. But when I was writing this question I thought that I might change position to `relative` when draggable is created, but then images also appear under another.

Is there a way to repair it?

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1enyLof5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ufff i did it. I made position: relative. And then i add two variables for calculation for height of all of previous images, and then I subtracted this height from top: property inside new image.